# How can I draw georeferenced WGS84 grid on Android?

Tags: android, grids-graticules, mobile-atlas-creator

I'm planning to display a grid which is georeferenced and show the lat/long of the particular location depending on zoom level.

I want to display something similar to what MOBAC has as an option called 'enable wgs grid'. Could anyone help me get started? Or any idea how can I draw georeferenced grid?

Comment: Are you using the Android Maps API v2?

Comment: No, I'm using OSMdroid library,